# How to achieve AppStore like header

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uinavigationbar, swift2

I'd like to ask you for advice how to make same kind of header like in AppStore. Check screen shots below. I also want to do it without navigation bar visible but this is only detail I can handle. Thanks for any idea!

[image: 1/2]

[image: 2/2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be easily done with `- headerViewForSection:`, in case you are using `UITableView`.

Comment: Thank you. I'll try and let you know:)

Comment: Just edited a proper name of method you should be using